# Returning Duplicates with Python BeautifulSoup using the find_all function

Tags: python, parsing, duplicates, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the following website http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/list/muscle/selected/biceps with the following code:

```
url = "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/list/muscle/selected/biceps"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
exercises = soup.find("div", {"id":"listResults"}).find_all('div',{'class':'exerciseName'})

for exercise in exercises:
    item =  exercise.find('a')
    print str(item.string)
```

I would expect the `find_all` component to return a BS object that contains all the segments from "Alternate Hammer Curl" to "Zottman Preacher Curl". However, it instead returns items from "Alternate Hammer Curl" to "Dumbell Prone Incline Curl" and then repeats this list without including the remaining portion of the exercises.

Has anyone had any similar issues where the `find-all` ends up returning an object with duplicated items such as this??

Comment: Using python3 your code works for me.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am running this in an ipython notebook using  Python 2.7.6. Could this be the reason why this is occuring? In any event I still don't quite understand why an older version would be causing this. I have been using BeautifulSoup with ipython for a number of months now and have never such an issue.

Comment: It works fine in Python 2.7.2 and 2.7.5 with IPython for me, both with bs4 4.3.2. What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: Problem resolved! It was a version issue with BS. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine both in Python 2.7 and 3.3 for me. You should check your BS installation. I haven't tried with anything other than BS4, but it might be different for other versions.